# How to make a row into a list in a two dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

Simplifying the question due to the confusion

lets say you have the following  code:

```
gameMap = [[0 for y in range(1)] for x in range(5)]
gameMap[0] = "absdasdasdasd"


print(gameMap)
list(gameMap[0])
print(gameMap)
```

Output:

> ['absdasdasdasd', [0], [0], [0], [0]] 
>   ['absdasdasdasd', [0], [0], [0], [0]]

I want:

> ['a','b','s',.....], [0], [0], [0], etc..

Comment: In Python char arrays and a list of characters are very similar and can be treated almost identically. Is there a specific reason you need a list instead of a string?

Comment: the reason is to have a game map, to have an index number for the players current position

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Show the data you are starting with, and show how you want it to end up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are really "thinking in python".  There are no arrays here, just lists.  I think what you want to end up with is a list of strings.

Try this:

```
gameMap = list()
with open('gameMap.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        gameMap.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: But you can access the data with two coordinates.  gameMap[3][7] is the seventh character in row 3, or the seventh column in row 3, if you like.  I don't understand what you want to do that you can't do with the data in this format.

Comment: When I run the code I posted, gameMap[3][7] is a blank, as expected.  Are you running the code I posted?

Comment: Okay, gameMap[3][7] works, it refers to that exact position. however why does it not separate characters when doing print(gameMap[3]). Thank you!

Comment: Well, gameMap[3] is a string.  Do you want blanks printed between the characters? Then use print(' '.join(list(gameMap[3]))).  You can substitute any separator you want for ' ' of course.